# Binary Search in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, search, binary-search

I have been trying to pick Haskell back up so I decided to try to implement binary search as practice. I am aware that binary search in Haskell in inefficient because Haskell's lists are implemented as linked lists, but I wanted to try it anyway. I would love to know how I could improve this or how it could be more idiomatic, thanks!

```hs
search :: (Ord a) => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
search _ [] = Nothing
search n h
  | elem == n = Just index
  | elem < n = (+index) . (+1) <$> (search n $ drop (index+1) h)
  | otherwise = search n $ take index h
  where index = length h `quot` 2
        elem = h !! index
```

Answer (score 5):

Since there is already a function called `elem`, I wouldn't call the element the same. There's no way that those two can get mistaken though, since their types differ. So you're safe at that point. However, you will still get a warning on `-Wall`.

Next, you call your list `h`. Lists are usually called `xs` (one `x`, may `x`ses), which makes it a little bit harder to catch than it needs to be. We can also split the list into the three parts at the same time:

```
search :: (Ord a) => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
search _ [] = Nothing
search n xs
  | elem == n = Just index
  | elem < n  = (+index) . (+1) <$> search n bs
  | otherwise = search n as
  where index = length xs `quot` 2
        (as,elem:bs) = splitAt index xs
```

This removes the need to traverse the list again just to get the correct init/tail, however it's harder to read, so it's up to you. Also, I really like to have the compiler yell at me if I forgot a case in my guards. For example, GHC will happily accept

```
search :: (Ord a) => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
search _ [] = Nothing
search n xs
  | elem == n = Just index
  | elem < n  = (+index) . (+1) <$> search n bs
  where ...
```

even *with* warnings. With `compare elem n`, we get warnings:

```
search n xs = case elem `compare` n of
    EQ -> Just index
    LT -> (+index) . (+1) <$> search n bs
    -- third missing, GHC warns us 
  where ...
```

But that's more or less a personal preference. A major nitpick though is that you take the `length` of the list in every iteration. You can get rid of that if you write another function:

```
search :: (Ord a) => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
search n ys = go (length ys) ys
  where
    go _ [] = Nothing
    go l xs = ...
```